# Indenting multiple lines of a paragraph

Tags: indentation, paragraphs, parindent

I am looking to indent the first 3-4 lines of a paragraph, and have the rest start normally at margin length (see attached photograph for example).

The `lettrine` package does this, but adding the big initial. I am looking to do this without having to add some visible or invisible figure to push the text aside.

[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! You have the `\hangpara` command from the `hanging` package for that.

Comment: Thank you! Just looked into it and it works perfectly fine. Thanks again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the `memoir` class

```
\hangpara{<num>}{<indent>}
The paragraph text.
```

where `<num>` is the number of lines to be indented by the amount `<indent>`.

For more on particular paragraph shapes you could look at https://tug.org/TUGboat/tb28-2/tbglister.pdf and https://tug.org/TUGboat/tb29-2/tbglister.pdf.

Comment: Well, thank you! I have just been looking into it and it works perfectly